# How can I stop overlapping(and somehow image 'dissapearing) in the .container element - desktop media query when i put align-items: ... => responsive

Tags: css

I have tried putting flex: 1 on both child elements of the .container(responsive - media query), and it's not working. Somehow my image (.container-img (div element)) is 'hiding'/overlapping/not showing.
I do not know where the issue might be in this case.
I would appreciate if someone more experienced took a look at this issue. Thank you!

```
<body>
  <main class="main-container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="container-img">
      </div>

      <div class="container-desc">
        <span class="secondary-title">PERFUME</span>
        <h1 class="main-title">Gabrielle Essence Eau De Parfum</h1>
        <p class="text">
          A floral, solar and voluptuous interpretation composed by Olivier Polge,
          Perfumer-Creator for the House of CHANEL.
        </p>
        <div class="price">
          <span class="price-current">$149.99</span>
          <span class="price-discount">$169.99</span>
        </div>
        <button class="cart">
          <img src="images/icon-cart.svg" alt="Shop">
          <span class="cart-shop">Add to Cart</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>




body {
    background: var(--clr-bg-main);
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

h1,
p {
    margin: 0;
}

.main-container {
    min-height: 100vh;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container {
    margin: 2rem 1rem;
    width: min(100% - 2rem, 800px);

    min-height: 80vh;    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.container-img {
    background: url('images/image-product-mobile.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;

    flex: 1;
}

.container-desc {
    background: var(--clr-neutral);
    padding: 2rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.main-title {
    font-family: 'Fraunces', serif;
    font-size: var(--fs-title-primary);
    line-height: 1;
    margin-top: 1rem;

}

.secondary-title,
.text,
.price-discount {
    color: var(--clr-dark-grayish-blue);
}

.secondary-title {
    font-size: var(--fs-title-secondary);
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.text {
    font-size: var(--fs-text-primary);
    margin-top: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.6;

}

.price {
    margin-top: 2rem;

    display: flex;
    gap: 2rem;
    align-items: center;
}

.price-current {
    font-family: 'Fraunces', serif;
    font-size: var(--fs-text-current-price);
    color: var(--clr-bg-button-price);

}

.price-discount {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

.cart {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: var(--clr-bg-button-price);
    font-size: var(--fs-text-button);
    font-weight: var(--fw-bold);
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
    padding: 1.5rem 6rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.cart:hover,
.cart:active {
    background: var(--clr-bg-button-hover);
}

.cart img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

.cart-shop {
    color: var(--clr-neutral);
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}




@media (min-width: 40em) {
    
    .container {
        min-height: 60vh;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;

    }

    .container-img {
        background: url('images/image-product-desktop.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    .container-desc {
        flex: 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i found the solution to this problem, which of course is pretty simple one. I have been focusing on the parent instead of a child element .container-desc specifically to put 'justify-items: center'.  Lack of concentration.